# When something is meaningless to you

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request, sentence-structure

What motivated people usually say in normal English when they tend to say something bad is meaningless for them? (I am looking for the most natural way to say this sentence.)

What comes to my mind (a direct translation) is something like:

> - (Surrounder / giving up) is meaningless for me.
> - "Impossible" is meaningless for me.

Etc.

But I have no idea how native speakers would say the same thing. In my language there is one single epidemic structure to convey this message. We can use it for any concept. E.g the above words. I would appreciate it if you could help me with t.

Comment: We use phrases like the ones user3169 and Javalatte have offered when our meaning is "That idea is completely alien to me; it is something I will never *do* (or countenance)".  For example: *I don't know the meaning of *compromise*" or "*Compromise* is not in my vocabulary". Or "Weekend?! We don't know the meaning of *weekend* at this company!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities, depending on who you are speaking to. With somebody educated, you could use one of these:

> Impossible isn't a word in my vocabulary.
>   Impossible is an alien concept.

With somebody less well educated, you might say

> I never use the word 'Impossible'.
>   Impossible? Don't know what it means, mate.

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

> I don't know the meaning of...

For example:

> I don't know the meaning of ***quitting/losing***".

You can substitute other words in this format depending on the context.